# How to know when bluetooth device is connected and Disconnected

Tags: android

Whenever I connect device it shows "ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED".. But it immediately shows that "ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED". I use this code.
When any device connect it shows Device Conneted but after sometime it shows Device Disconnected though device is still connected.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Device found");
            //Device found
        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Device is now connected");
            //Device is now connected
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Done searching");
            //Done searching
        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Device is about to disconnect");
            //Device is about to disconnect
        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Device has disconnected");
            //Device has disconnected
        }
    }
};

private void registerBluetoothreceiver() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }
}
```